# The specified type member 'TimeBandDescription' is not supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have code that looks something like this bug getting error: the specified type member 'TimeBandDescription' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported. How do I make this AsEnuermable?

```
public partial class TimeBand
{
    public TimeBand()
    {
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public long From { get; set; }

    public long To { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string TimeBandDescription => $"{Name} ({TicksToHhMmFormat(From)} - {TicksToHhMmFormat(To)})";

    private static string TicksToHhMmFormat(long ticks)
    {
        if (ticks == long.MaxValue)
        {
            return "Max";
        }
        var timeSpan = new TimeSpan(ticks);
        return $"{(int)timeSpan.TotalHours}{timeSpan.ToString(@"\:mm")}";
    }
}

public class SuplierService : ISuplierService
{
        public SupplierInfoModel GetSupplierList(int supplierId)
            {
                var query = (from s in suppliers
                             join tb in TimeBands on s.fkTimeBandId equals tb.Id
                             where s.supplierId == supplierId
                             select new SupplierInfoModel
                             {
                                 SupplierId = supplierId,
                                 SupplierEmail = s.Email,
                                 Phone = s.Phone,
                                 Fax = s.Fax,
                                 TimeBandDescription = tb.TimeBandDescription,
```

Comment: Why are you using `TimeBandDescription` in your query if you explicitly mark it `[NotMapped]`?

Comment: TimeBand is also associated with a table and TimeBandDescription is [notmapped] since it is not stored data.

Answer (score 0):

I have a working solution but not the prettiest.

```
    join tb in TimeBands on s.fkTimeBandId equals tb.Id
    from tband in timeband.DefaultIfEmpty()




                var Results = (from s in suppliers
                                             join tb in TimeBands on s.fkTimeBandId equals tb.Id
                                             where s.supplierId == supplierId
                         select new
                            {
                                TimeBand = tband,
                                Supplier = new HotelInfoModel
                                {
                                                 SupplierId = supplierId,
                                                 SupplierEmail = s.Email,
                                                 Phone = s.Phone,
                                                 Fax = s.Fax,
                                                 //TimeBandDescription = tb.TimeBandDescription, // no longer needed
                                                . . .
                            }
                        }).ToList();                                    

                        foreach (var result in Results)
                        {
                            result.Supplier.TimeBandDescription = result.TimeBand?.TimeBandDescription ?? "No Time Band Desc";
                        }

        var suppliers = Results.Select(s => s.Supplier).ToList();
```